# How i can write new_column in where?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

```
SELECT  *,STUFF((SELECT ',' + struktur_bolmesi
FROM tb_Structure WHERE  concat(',',bolmeler,',')  LIKE concat('%,',struktur_id,',%')
FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') as new_column from tb_Customers where new_column like '%text%'
```

Comment: [`SELECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) - please scroll down to "Logical Processing Order of the Select Statement" - "because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses..." - `WHERE` is step 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this

```
 WITH Tbl AS(
            SELECT  *,STUFF((SELECT ',' + struktur_bolmesi
    FROM tb_Structure WHERE  concat(',',bolmeler,',')  LIKE concat('%,',struktur_id,',%')
    FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') 
            as new_column from tb_Customers
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Tbl
    WHERE   new_column LIKE '%text%'
```